# Cannot alter a table with primary key using Fluent Migrator

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, fluent-migrator

I am trying to use Fluent Migrator to alter a table to add a column which is a Guid, not nullable and primary key.

Example: **test_user** (table)

+++++++++

col1     col2

+++++++++

test1    test2

test3    test4

+++++++++

I am using the below syntax to add a column to an existing table:

```
    Alter.Table("test_user").AddColumn("test_user_id").AsGuid().NotNullable().WithDefault(SystemMethods.NewGuid);

    Create.PrimaryKey("pk_test_user")
        .OnTable("test_user").Column("test_user_id");
```

If the table has data like in the example it should add unique Guid's

**error:** "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT UUID())'"

Answer (score 0):

You must have version [8.0.13](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) or higher of MySQL to use default values.